Bad kerning in naïve
I'm writing a paper to a journal, and I'm using the word naïve, but it looks bad in the pdf, with the i looking like it's pushed too far to the left:

Compare this to how it looks in this minimal tex file:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

na\"ive

\end{document}


In the first example, I have tried entering the word in the tex file as naïve, na\"ive, and even na{\"i}ve, but it looks the same in all cases. Is there anything I can do about this, or is it just the case that this journal uses a crappy font where the letter ï doesn't look quite right?
Update
Here is a minimal example of the unwanted behaviour. This uses Elsevier's documentclass cas-sc, which came with my TeXlive installation (I'm using MacTeX 2024). Note that the document won't compile without natbib, even if there are no citations in the document. Not sure why.
\documentclass{cas-sc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
na\"ive
\end{document}


Why don't you provide a small example showing the problem? As it is now, you do not even tell what font it is you are using.

Added an example now.

You can reduce to
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
na\"ive
\showoutput
\end{document}

which shows that there is no kerning and this is just how the font is set up. If we switch to stix2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
na\"ive
\end{document}

the issue is fixed (the font is a second release). This can be applied to the class you are using
\documentclass{cas-sc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
na\"ive
\end{document}


It does indeed fix the problem, but it also changes the look of the document quite a bit, so I'm not sure if the journal will be too happy about it. On the other hand, papers published by Elsevier's journals typically look very different from the documents I compile from LaTeX myself, so I guess I'll just have to wait until I see the final version and complain then.

@Tor Almost certainly the journal is not typeset with LaTeX - but in the end that's the publishers issue

The original STIX font release was not great - changing the appearance here is really fixing that
